# How to implement a callback URL to receive a json data in c#

Tags: c#, json

For some days now i have been struggling on a project where i need to provide a URL to enable me to receive a JSON response(precisely this my first time of calling a web API)
This is the scenario:
- First the company has a web service that i need to consume and send a bill prompt to our client and so far it has been successful
- Second , they ask me to implement a callback and give them the URL where they will call me to send the status of the bill whether our client has confirm the bill prompt or not(this is where i am stacked)
When i get the JSON data i can easily use it to do what i want but my problem is how to implement the web page that the company will call to send the status.
Please a sample code will help me a lot.Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This is not a code writing service. I recommend you look into making a WebAPI project in C# to get started. There are a lot of pieces involved in setting up a site to receive a callback like this, so you will no doubt have questions. If you come back here with more specific problems along the way we will be able to help you much better. If you do, please check out [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking again.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is called [WebAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api). You expose HTTP endpoints using Controllers to the Internet and consumers of your API may utilize them to `POST` the status back.

Answer (score 0):

You are describing creating an API. Basically, you create an endpoint url using a controller in C#. It's within this controller that you receive data from "the company" and process it, and do whatever you need to do after that. If you use the standard MVC framework build into C#, it's fairly straight-forward. Here is an example of a callback url we are using in a three-legged OAuth procedure. The last step involves a third party sending a request to our callback url and posting  some data. We are using a model as a parameter. But you can use simple structures (`int`, `string`, etc) as well. As log as the names of your params match the names that the third party sends in their query string or POST, the MVC framework will handle the variable assignment automatically. The serialization/deserialization is built in to the framework.

Here is a small example of how we have implemented a callback url in one of our apps:

```
public class MyAuthenticatedController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index([FromUri]MyAuthenticatedModel model)
    {
        logTheResponse(model);
        if (model == null)
        {
            throw new HttpException(401, "Auth Failed");
        }
    }
}
```

The third party would hit the url:

http://app.mydomain.com/myauthenticated

Using the GET method.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to build an ASP.NET Web API Project, you can do this easily with an [Azure Function](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/).

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-generic-webhook-triggered-function